# Classlist.add in a shorter way?

Tags: javascript

Hey I have to give some list items their own classes. But my way of doing it is a bit too much. Is there a way to make this cleaner with a loop or something like that?

**Javascript:**

```
function classAdden() {
    var element = document.querySelectorAll("LI");
    element[0].classList.add("javascript"); // Javascript
    element[1].classList.add("tinkiewinkie"); // Tinkie Winkie
    element[2].classList.add("dipsi"); // Dipsi
    element[3].classList.add("php"); // PHP
    element[4].classList.add("lala"); // Lala
    element[5].classList.add("po"); // Po
    element[6].classList.add("jquery"); // jQuery
}
```

Comment: Yes, you could make it shorter by using an array and a loop, have you tried that yet?

Comment: @certainPerformance I gave looping a try but I couldnt get it to work. Thats why I am asking this question.

Comment: Use JQuery would be simpler i guess.

Comment: @J.Coderino can you show the code with the loop that you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the values in `array` and use `forEach()`

```
const arr = ["javascript","tinkiewinkie","dipsi","php","lala","po","jquery"]; 
function classAdden() {
     const element = document.querySelectorAll("LI"); 
     arr.forEach((a,i) => element[i].classList.add(a)); 
}
```

Comment: Shorter: `const arr = ["javascript","tinkiewinkie","dipsi","php","lala","po","jquery"];
function classAdden() {
    const element = document.querySelectorAll("LI");
    arr.forEach((a,i) => element[i].classList.add(a));
}`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
const names = ["javascript", ..., "jquery"];
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    element[i].classList.add(names[i]);
```

?